# how to call a react hook in a button click callback in react-admin or what to do instead?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin, react-final-form

React-admin provides hooks like `useGetOne` and `useCreate` to read and write data using rest calls.

I need to create a new record in a button callback function after collecting some data from different sources. Unfortunately it is not allowed to call react hooks from callbacks. So what can I do instead?

My problem is that I still haven't understood how REACT and final-form works. I'm from the ASP.NET corner, so I'm familiar with the concept of controls, which is obviously quite remarkably different.

The code below throws the following error at runtime:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
>   of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See /*link removed*/ for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

The error occurs inside `GetMeasurementTemplate()` which uses another hook `getOne()` to fetch a record.

```
const createMeasurementJob = ( record ) => {
        var counter = 0;
        if (record.freimessen.messungen.length > 0) {
            record.freimessen.messungen.forEach(element => {
                counter++;
                var job = {};
                job.internalOrderNumber = "TEST" + record.id + "-" + counter;
                const measurement = GetMeasurementTemplate(element.ort);
                job.locationId = measurement.location;
                job.substanceIds = measurement.substances;
                job.comment = element.kommentar;
                job.assigneeId = element.gaspruefer;
                job.date = record.arbeit.ab;

                // #### error: invalid hook call ####
                const [create, { loading, error }] = useCreate('jobs', job);  //* BANG! *//
                if (error) { return false }
            })
        }
        return true;
    };

   const GetMeasurementTemplate = (id) => {
      // #### error: invalid hook call ####
      const { data, loading, error } = useGetOne('LocationSubstanceMapping', id);
      if (loading) { return <LinearProgress />; }
      if (error) { return <p>ERROR</p>; }
      return data;
    };

    const CSEButton = ({ handleSubmitWithRedirect, ...props }) => {
        const form = useForm();
        var formdata = form.getState().values;
        const handleClick = useCallback(() => {

            createMeasurementJob(formdata)
        }, [form]);

        return <SaveButton {...props} handleSubmitWithRedirect={handleClick} />;
    };
```

Comment: You are breaking the Rules of Hooks. Don't call hooks in loops and non-functional components.

Comment: I know, but what is the solution?

Comment: You need to refactor your code so your hooks are called **only** from a react functional component. `CSEButton` is obviously a component. Is `GetMeasurementTemplate` a component? It is PascalCased like a react component but doesn't take props (unless `id` is props) and doesn't always return valid JSX. This may involve some refactoring of logic within your hooks as well. Can you also include your hooks to see what can be sussed out into a utility/callback function? It could even be that hooks aren't even the right tool for the job.